# Seekbar is still not updating

Tags: android, seekbar

I made these two method to update seekbar every 100ms:

```
public void updateSeekBar() {

    handler.postDelayed(mUpdateTimeTask, 100);
}

private Runnable mUpdateTimeTask = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        mySeekBar.setMax(mySong.getDuration());
        x = mySong.getCurrentPosition();
        mySeekBar.setProgress(x);
        handler.postDelayed(this, 100);
    }
};
```

and put it inside my playMusic method:

```
public void playMusic() {

    //just a test from intent.getExtra

    if(test.equalsIgnoreCase("Jason Mraz")) {
        mySong = MediaPlayer.create(MusicClass.this, jm[musicCounter]);
        displaySong(jm);
        songNumbers = jm.length;


    }else if(test.equalsIgnoreCase("fob")) {
        mySong = MediaPlayer.create(MusicClass.this, fob[musicCounter]);
        displaySong(fob);
        songNumbers = fob.length;

    }else if(test.equalsIgnoreCase("ed")) {
        mySong = MediaPlayer.create(MusicClass.this, ed[musicCounter]);
        displaySong(ed);
        songNumbers = ed.length;

    }


    //when the song is completed

    mySong.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
            nextSong();
        }
    });

    //seekbar update

    mySeekBar.setMax(mySong.getDuration());
    mySeekBar.setProgress(0);
    mySong.start();

    updateSeekBar();

}
```

this is my onCreate method:

```
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.music);

    artistName = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.artistName);
    song = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.song);
    musicCounter = 0;
    ifPlaying = true;
    isRandom = false;
    random = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.random);
    stop = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.stop);
    myImageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.myImageView);
    dice = new Random();
    mySeekBar = (SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.mySeekBar);


    test = getIntent().getStringExtra("test");
    if(test.equalsIgnoreCase("Jason Mraz")) {
        artistName.setText("Jason Mraz");
        displayPP();
        songNumbers = jm.length;
        myImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.jason_mraz);
    } else if (test.equalsIgnoreCase("fob")) {
        artistName.setText("Fall Out Boys");
        displayPP();
        songNumbers = fob.length;
        myImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.fall_out_boys);
    } else if (test.equalsIgnoreCase("ed")) {
        artistName.setText("Ed Sheeran");
        displayPP();
        songNumbers = ed.length;
        myImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ed_sheeran);
    }

    playMusic();




    mySeekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int i, boolean b) {
            if (b) {
                mySong.seekTo(i);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
            mySong.pause();
        }

        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
            if (ifPlaying == true) {
                mySong.start();
            } else {
                return;
            }
        }
    });
}
```

My application says Unfortunately stopped. But when I remove the updateSeekbar in playMusic method it works fine, but without the updating seekBar every second. The setOnSeekBarChangeListener works perfectly fine, the only problem is I can't make updateSeekBar method work because it is alwats stopping my application and force exit.

Comment: wrap your code inside `runOnUiThread` method, if it's out side of your activity or fragment then use context to call this method.

Answer (score 0):

The symptoms you are describing is called an [ANR](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/vitals/anr). It means that you is doing to much work in the main thread.

What you need todo is review what you are triggering in your **mUpdateTimeTask**.

Next make sure your handler is running on the UI since your are updating views:

```
Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
```